# Не работает событие «on» на динамический элемент

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Нужно изменить динамически созданный через ajax элемент. 
Простейший пример: 
Допустим, #childDiv — это динамически созданный элемент Select внутри слоя #parentDiv. Хочу отследить его изменение:

```
$('#parentDiv').on('change','#childDiv',function () {
    console.log('Changed');
});
```

Так не работает.

Когда меняю #parentDiv на document:

```
$(document).on('change','#childDiv',function () {
    console.log('Changed');
});
```

работает.

Такая же история и с body. Работает только с родительским селектором document.

Как сделать, чтобы работало с селектором #parentDiv?

Comment: А вы случайно не пересоздаете  #parentDiv время от времени?

Comment: on.change - событие для изменения value, которые отрабатывают в input'ах, и select'ах.

Comment: @NeedHate, #childDiv — это и есть селект

Comment: @PavelMayorov, не работает даже с body. Его точно не пересоздаю)

Comment: перед выполнением `$('#parentDiv').on` попробуй вывести в консоль `$('#parentDiv').length`, судя по всему, в момент когда ты вызываешь скрипт, у тебя еще нет элемента parentDiv

Comment: @SokIvan можете обяснить зачем нужно что бы работал так `$('#parentDiv').on('change'.......` а не на `$(document).on(....`.

Comment: @Grundy, сам parentDiv создаётся в самом начале

Comment: @SokIvan, не важно когда он создается. Важно когда выполняется скрипт. Просто выведи количество найденных элементов, перед тем как пытаешься использовать on и посмотри сколько выведется

Comment: @razmik, исключительно с точки зрения быстродействия. И хочу понять, почему не работает через parentDiv

Comment: добавь еще где на странице находится вызываемый скрипт: в head? в body? еще где?

Comment: @SokIvan тогда можете не ждать ответа, его не будет, так будут работать только событие тех элементов которые генерируються во время загруски страницы, а для остольных надо сделать либо по второму вашему примару либо так ՝$('.#childDiv).live('change',function(){})՝. но метод `live` усторевший.

Comment: @Grundy точно, кажется, понял в чем дело. Отслеживание события находится вне $(document).ready

Comment: правильнее не отслеживание, а подписка на событие.